# What are the factors, aside from RAM, limiting Numpy array size and can they be adjusted?

Tags: python, memory, numpy

Say I create an array:

```
a=np.ones((21600,13,3,128),dtype=complex)
```

I get a memory error.

If I half the size of the array (n.b this took >10mins to create on my machine):

```
b=np.ones((10800,13,3,128),dtype=complex)
```

Its size in GB is:

```
b.nbytes/1024**3 = 0.803375244140625 GB
```

This is well below the amount of RAM in my laptop (2GB) - Therefore, I would have assumed that creating 'a' should have worked. What are the limiting factors stopping me from dealing with such big arrays?

Ideally, I would like to create an array of shape `(86400,13,3,128)` with `dtype=complex`.

Is there any way to do this without splitting it up?

Comment: Wait, `a` and `b` have the same dimensions and the same `dtype`?

Comment: sounds like its swapping - did you check with top in a terminal? or are you using windows?

Comment: sorry, poor copy and paste skills.. updated question.

Comment: @usethedeathstar I am using windows (but setting up script to run on Linux machine with 4GB RAM)

Comment: Memory fragmentation may play a role, esp. with 32-bit NumPy. You need 1.6GB of *contiguous* virtual memory for array `a`.

Comment: _Is there any way to do this without splitting it up?_ - you can buy more RAM.

Comment: Running numpy on a 4GB laptop with Windows, I rarely could get hold of more than 2GB in a single array, the rest being taken up by the OS. Windows uses a lot of your PC resources. I recently threw less than $100 at it, and with 12GB the grass looks much greener...

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop has 2GB ram and `a` would take 1.6 of this, then chances are pretty high that there's not enough memory. Windows, your browser, mail etc will take quite a bunch of this already.

As an additional complication, numpy will need a single, contiguous 1.6 GB block of memory.
Which lowers the chances of having such a big block even more.

If your application/use case permits, it might be worth trying to store your data in a sparse matrix. This only stores non-zero elements - which can save a lot of memory (or not):
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html